# error: Unexpected token: name

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I am working to build an app using Vue.js. In my app, I have a single file component. That component looks like this:

**myComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <ul class="list-inline" v-if="isAvailable">
      <li><button @click="orderNow">order now</button></li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    export default {
        name: 'dataTable',
        data: function () {
            return {
                isAvailable:true
            };
        },
        methods: {
          orderNow: function() {
            let total = 5 + 2;
            alert(total);
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict";

const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/js/app.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'common' }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        publicPath: "/js/",
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/js/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue']
    }
```

When I run Webpack from the command line, I receive an error that says:

*Unexpected token: name (isAvailable)*

I've narrowed it down to the line: `let total = 5 + 2;`. I know that the `let` keyword is the issue. From my understanding, this error is happening because Uglify requires ES5 code. However, I thought I was sending ES5 code to Uglify by using the Babel loader. As shown in the webpack config, the preset is set to es2015. What am I doing wrong?
    };

Comment: Is this a project created with the vue-cli?

Comment: Will it work if you put vue loader before babel? This is how the vue-cli sets it up.

Comment: @HMR - I didn't think the order of the rules mattered. I tried your idea and it did NOT work. However, it was a great idea and I want to thank you for sharing.

Comment: @sandrooco - This project was not created with the vue-cli.